# Python 3.2 "TypeError: Can't convert 'type' object to str implicitly"

Tags: python, string, function, printing, echo

I am getting an error and I don't know how to refine my code.

Basically, what I am trying to do is pseudo `echo` command in a terminal app.

```
while True:
    foo = input("~ ")
    bar = str
    if foo in commands:
        eval(foo)()
    elif foo == ("echo "+ bar):
        print(bar)
    else:
        print("Command not found")
```

Obviously, it's not working.

Does anybody know what I need to use to accomplish this project?

Comment: Please give the complete error message.  Also, what are you expecting this code to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a variable `bar` and set it equal to `str`, which is the string type.  You then try to add this to the string `"echo "`.  This obviously won't work.  What are you trying to do with `bar`?  `bar` isn't connected to the user input, so it will never change no matter what the user types.

If you want to see if the input begins with "echo" and then if so print the rest, you can do this:

```
if foo.startswith("echo "):
    print foo[5:]
```

`str` doesn't mean "any string"; it's the type of all strings.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of Python.

Comment: What I want to do is if the input is "echo"+ (any string), print(the string)

Comment: Ahh, this works perfectly, I read it wrong the first time because somebody was distracting me, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This code is probably giving you problems:

```
"echo "+ bar
```

`bar` is equal to `str`, which is a data type.

Here's how I'd fix your code:

```
while True:
    command = input("~ ")    # Try to use good variable names

    if command in commands:
        commands[command]()  # Avoid `eval()` as much as possible.
    elif command.startswith('echo '):
        print(command[5:])   # Chops off the first five characters of `foo`
    else:
        print("Command not found")
```

Comment: I figured if I assigned bar as a string it might work but obviously didn't

Comment: I tried your method, but I got this:

      File "./shell.py", line 19, in main
        commands[command]()
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str